# Is there something in Jetty that limits json length/size responses?

Tags: java, apache-spark, jetty

I am experiencing an issue:

Migrated an application from tomcat to jetty, and there is a `json response that has more than 150k lines`, after migrating to jetty we notice the json is incomplete, and so checking the json only has 130k lines, however it is well formed (starts and ends with the correct {} or []), I never had this issue with tomcat but searching I found stuff like the `maxPostSize` attribute for tomcat, but can not find anything related to json responses size/length for jetty, any suggestions?

This application is in java-spark

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in Jetty that limits HTTP response sizes.  There are many projects that send multi-gigabyte responses, along with test cases within Jetty itself that do the same.

If you have an example project that replicates this behavior, file an issue at https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues and link to the project. (best idea is to link to a github project that has either a maven or gradle build, and explain the steps to replicate the behavior)

Comment: Okay ty, atleast this helps me discard this possibility